# How to get different rows from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, union, union-all

I'm trying to build a query that can give me the different rows between two tables.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    string searchquery = "SELECT* FROM NewList EXCEPT SELECT* FROM Restaurants UNION All";

    SqlCommand searchcom = new SqlCommand(searchquery, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(searchcom);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    connection.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(er.Message);
    return;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'All'.

What is the correct way/syntax to use `Union All` in `SqlCommand` class? I've tried to put it it my query string in too many ways but it's giving me the same error every time. How can I implement it in my search query with correct syntax ?

Comment: "What is the correct way/syntax to use Union All ?" isn't it? you just wrote invalid SQL query, and in the example, it shows how to write a valid query using UNION ALL

Comment: What is the correct way/syntax to use Union All in SqlCommand query string. That's the question.

Comment: Are you trying to find the rows in one table that are not present in the other?

Comment: @AsheraH yes. There are nearly 26000 rows in "NewList" and 25000 rows in "Restaurants". I'm trying to get that new 1000 row to a datagridview

Comment: remove the `UNION ALL` from your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is incorrect from `UNION ALL` on.

You can try it like this:

```
string searchquery = "SELECT * FROM NewList UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Restaurants ";
```

However, you need to be aware that:

1. It **does not remove duplicate rows** between the various `SELECT` statements (all rows are returned)
2. Each `SELECT` statement within the `UNION ALL` **must have the same number of columns in the result sets with similar data types**

Read [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php) for more details.

**Updated**

You should use `EXCEPT` instead of `UNION ALL` if you want to get rows in one table that are not present in the other one.

Comment: Thank you. There are nearly 26000 rows in "NewList" and 25000 rows in "Restaurants". I'm trying to get that new 1000 row to a datagridview. This doesn't give me that result

Comment: I don't think the **The number of fields** of 2 table are the same. BTW, give us your sample data of 2 table and your expectation result value. Then we can give you advise.

Comment: It seems that you should you `Except` instead of `Union All`

Comment: Number of fields, column names, data types and datas are all the same in two tables. And except doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you try on run my query in sql server?

Comment: SELECT * FROM NewList EXCEPT  SELECT * FROM Restaurants

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Checking.RestID, FROM 
(SELECT RestID FROM NewList EXCEPT Select RestID from Restaurants) as Checking
LEFT JOIN NewList ON Checking.RestID = NewList.RestID
```

this worked, thanks to anyone !

Comment: Yes, As i said before, you should use `Except` instead of `UNION ALL`. BTW, Don't forget give me an upvote. I really appreciate that. @Bora